# AVR32DA28 phase and frequency correct PWM

Tags: c, embedded, avr, microchip

[AVR32DA28 Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/AVR32DA28-32-48-Data-Sheet-40002228B.pdf) I am trying to make a pwm with phase and frequency correct and with two signal one should be inverted and another should be non inverted..
I have prepared some line of code as followed

```c
int8_t PWM_0_init()
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = 0x1f4; /* Setting: 0x1f4 */

    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1 = 0x1f4; /* Setting: 0x1f4 */

    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = 0 << TCA_SINGLE_ALUPD_bp         /* Auto Lock Update: disabled */
                        | 1 << TCA_SINGLE_CMP0EN_bp      /* Setting: enabled */
                        | 1 << TCA_SINGLE_CMP1EN_bp      /* Setting: enabled */
                        | 0 << TCA_SINGLE_CMP2EN_bp      /* Setting: disabled */
                        | TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_DSBOTTOM_gc; /*  */

    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV1_gc /* System Clock */
                        | 1 << TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bp /* Module Enable: enabled */;
}

void PWM_0_load_top(PWM_0_register_t top_value)
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.PERBUF = top_value;
}

void PWM_0_load_duty_cycle_ch0(PWM_0_register_t duty_value)
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0BUF = duty_value;
}


void PWM_0_load_duty_cycle_ch1(PWM_0_register_t duty_value)
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1BUF = duty_value;
}

int main(void)
{

    PWM_0_load_top(0X65);

    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) {
        PWM_0_load_duty_cycle_ch0(45.45);
        PWM_0_load_duty_cycle_ch1(45.45);
    }
}
```

this is it, here i am getting non inverted signals from both of the channels. Can anyone tell me what could make this better as i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add links in the question to the datasheet or any other reference documentation you used? Myself and others don't necessarily know *this* microcontroller, but we know microcontrollers and how to figure this out, and it helps your helpers help you faster.

Comment: Also, do you have a particular dev board or device you're using, in case we want to buy one?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Added the link and I have designed my own pcb for this microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed your broken link. See the edit history.

Comment: @GabrielStaples sorry for being late, did you find any solution for me.

Comment: No, I am unable to make the time to investigate at this time.

Comment: The tag `avr32` is reserved for 32-bit AVR32 architecture, not to be confused with 8-bit AVR.  Comfusingly, AVR32DA28 is an 8-bit AVR, not a 32-bit AVR32.

Answer (score 0):

Inversion is not a TCA property but property of the IO pin itself. This way it works for any use -- software output control and input reading, timer output compare and input capture, uart, interrupt etc.
See Figure 17-1. PORT Block Diagram on page 157, "invert enable" line.

To enable inversion on the desired TCA output one should set `INVEN` bit in corresponding `PORTx.PINnCTRL` register